# Testing if my program is executed from the bash/ksh/csh command line

Tags: c, linux

I would like to know if my program is executed from a command line, or executed through `system()` call, or from a script.

I initially thought about getting parent id (`getppid()`), and looking up `/proc/#pppid` directory checking either the `exe` link or contents of the `cmdline` file. If it is /bin/bash, or /bin/csh, or /bin/sh I would know that it runs from the command line.

The problem is that it is **not true**, because a standalone script would also tell me `/bin/bash`.
Even if it worked, it could have been very specific Linux version approach and could stop working in a future.

Is there a better way to do that?

Thank you for any advice or pointing out to some direction.

Comment: check the terminal status? If you run from the cli, you get a full terminal. if you run under exec() or other methods, you don't get an interactive terminal.

Comment: @MarcB - Thank you for the response. Can you elaborate please? `stty()` - if this is what you think of - is not implemented in my Linux.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26676/how-to-check-if-a-shell-is-login-interactive-batch

Comment: @MarcB - Looks great :) What should I call to get what `echo $-` uses? Remember that I need a C function rather than bash extension.

Comment: @MarcB - I think it may be `int isatty(int desc);` Now, I need to test it!

Comment: @MarcB - Nope. `isatty(1)` will only tell me that the input comes from the terminal, and not that my program is executed from bash...

Comment: `isatty(1)` tells you the _output_ goes to a terminal; `isatty(0)` would tell you about _input_.  And `system()` can be used with output going to terminal and you can run it from the command line with input coming from files and output going to files.  What are you really needing to know?  There's an element of an XY Problem here.  What is the problem you are trying to solve by determining whether the program was run via `system()`?  As you've found, `system` is usually implemented so that it runs a shell, perhaps Bash, with `-c` and 'what you provided as an argument to `system()`'.

Comment: The problem is that these different contexts (command line/script/system()) are _very_ similar to each other (intentionally), so that any means of distinguishing them would be a definite hack (finding out if there's an attached terminal might indeed help, but it's a dubious heuristic). Can you say why you want to know this? There might be a clear solution to that problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - The requirement is rather strange, but I have been asked to disable some arguments from the the program that is launched from a command line which can store the whole set of arguments to the history file.

Comment: if you try it, the history file will still contain it...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - yes, however, that is not the point. This option will be disabled for regular office user except when used in a script or called from programs. That is the requirement I got.

Comment: @Grzegorz but if usage is allowed from a script, then all a command-line user has to do is write a script `#! /bin/sh -\nyour-magic-command "$@"` and suddenly they're allowed. Perhaps check for a special `ENABLE_MAGIC_COMMAND=yes` environment variable, or a lock file which only the `system()`-calling program can write. If the special arguments are, say, passwords, then an environment variable or named pipe might be how to pass them to a `system()` child in a way that a command-line would find difficult – these wouldn't find their way to the history.

Comment: @NormanGray Yes, you are right. It's a messy project anyway :D More a political game for one particular very influential customer. They realize one can write a script. The same as with ftp lacking username and password. Well, we are still have discussion what to do.

Comment: Please edit the question rather than putting additional information in comments

Comment: Tell them that if they need a security measure, one can be implemented with standard Unix security tools (permissions and setuid bits). If they need something that can satisfy a non-technical boss until someone screws up and inflicts a couple billion dollars worth of damage, that can be done too.

Comment: @n.m I absolutely understand you, but the question is still valid, and now, out of shear curiosity I wonder if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most shells written since 1980 support job control, which is implemented by assigning a process group to each process in a pipeline of commands. The process group is set by [setpgrp()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setpgrp.html), which sets the process's pgrp to its pid.

The pgrp is inherited across forks.

So, if your shell is a relatively modern one, a program started by an interactive shell will have `getpid() == getpgrp()`, and any additional processes forked by that process (say, if it's a shell script or if it calls `system()`) will have `getpid() != getpgrp()`.

Here's a test program, and its behavior under bash (it will behave the same under ksh93 and tcsh as well):

pp.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("pid=%d pgrp=%d\n", (int)getpid(), (int)getpgrp());
}
```

```
$ ./pp
pid=3164 pgrp=3164
$ ./pp &
[1] 3165
$ pid=3165 pgrp=3165
```

In a pipeline, the leftmost command is the process group leader. (This isn't documented, but bash, ksh93, and tcsh all do it this way).

```
$ ls|./pp
pid=3179 pgrp=3178
$ ./pp|cat
pid=3180 pgrp=3180
```

A program called with `system()` will have the same pgrp as its parent:

pps.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    system("./pp");
}
```

```
$ ./pps
pid=4610 pgrp=4608
```

In a shell script, the shell is the process group leader, and any command invoked by it will inherit the pgrp:

pp.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
./pp
```

```
$ ./pp.sh
pid=4501 pgrp=4500
```

But if the shell script `exec`s a program, the pid doesn't change, and the execed program will be a process group leader, so you probably don't want to do that.

ppe.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
exec ./pp
```

```
$ ./ppe.sh
pid=4504 pgrp=4504
```

In the unlikely case that the user turns off job control, every command is going to have the same pgrp as the shell:

```
$ set +m
$ ./pp
pid=4521 pgrp=2990
$ ./pp
pid=4522 pgrp=2990
```

Comment: I'm sorry to come back to you so late. I have completely missed that question and your answer, and I don't remember how did that happen. I have read your answer and I believe - despite the fact that I won't be using it now, that your thorough analysis answers my question. Therefore I am upping it and marking as the answer. Thanks a lot, Mark.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept signal from PID when the script is done and check "kill" for it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that solves your problem but environment variables can give you a good hint. For example:

```
 $ set | grep "^_="
 _=
 $ bash -c "set" | grep "^_="
 _=/bin/bash
 $ sh -c "set" | grep "^_="
 _='/bin/sh'
```